# Representation of repetitive dates in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, database-schema

In my program I must manage some holidays. Each holiday can be an exact date, or a repetitive date.

For example:

```
-6th January of each years
-first day of each month of each year
```

How would you I save this information on db?
I can't use `Datetime` because with datetime I can't represent the particular cases like in the above example.

Any suggestion?

If it may concern, I am using **TSQL**

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: if I have understood correctly,you want to store Holiday list in table.for that keep one column as only date (not datetime).so holidayname varchar(255),HoliDate Date.

Comment: I would create a calendar table, populate it with 20 years worth of data and not worry about encoding the rules for how it's populated within the database itself. Save those in a script/stored procedure that you can run (if needs by) in another ten years time.

Comment: Use iCalendar RRules and ExDates, and generate the actual dates (in a time window) with a materialized view and some C#

Answer (score 2):

The simple approach, without knowing more about your usage of these data, will be to have three numeric fields `day`, `month`, `year` and interpret them this way: If all three are filled, it's exactly that day and no other day. If year isn't filled, it's the day and month, repeating every year. If only the day is filled, it's the day, repeating every month.

If you have more intricate repetition schemes, you'll need an attribute for the repetition rule, like "every three months".

Of course, every query will need to contain some logic to interpret this scheme, but that's inevitable, unless you decide to have a list of all holidays, say the next 50 years.

Comment: interesting way of thinking +1

Comment: Hi, how can we specify weekdays, ie Every Sunday, or Every Second Saturday  etc?

Comment: No requirement for that in the OP's problem description. Of course, you can define an entire domain specific language for describing date functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 3 column design to store this conditions

1. Column to Specify whether this is a `Day` or `WeekDay`
2. Column to Specify `Day/WeekDay  Number` (ie 1 to 30/31 for Day, 1 to 7 for WeekDay)
3. Column to Specify `Monthly/Yearly` occurrence.(means every month/year)

Eg:- For first day of each month,Something like this :     `DAY,1,MONTHLY`

For Second Saturday of every month : `WEEKDAY,14*,MONTHLY` (*My Week start is Sunday)

This is not a perfect solution, you may have to add some more column to meet your business logic completely.

Comment: @davidinho, can you plz share the design you are used to handle the scenario.